Question About Federated Deeply Coupled GPS - INS Integration
I am trying to create a Deeply Coupled System that combines GPS with IMU sensor on the Receiver Level. Right now I am having some difficulties regarding the Pre-Filter part of the Filter.
The Pre-Filter is a Linear Kalman Filter which operates on each tracking channel of the GPS receiver separately. Its states are Carrier-Phase Error, Carrier-Frequency Error, Carrier-Frequency Rate Error, Code-Phase error.
I have the following Prediction step equation.

My problem is this prediction step is hugely dependent on the frequency rate error (fourth state, w_dot) and I have no idea how I can obtain this information from the Tracking Loop. What I can get from the Tracking Loop is the Code Phase, Carrier Phase, Carrier Frequency, and etc. Should I be numerically differentiating the Carrier Frequency in order to have the Frequency Rate? I tried initializing the Pre-Filter with a relatively small values of w_dot, however after some update/correction steps, the Kalman Gain entry which correspond to the w_dot state become greater than 1 and system becomes unstable; which makes me think that I should be a getting w_dot information from somewhere in the Tracking loops.
